# writing new custom mvc4 membership provider

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4, membership-provider

After I had read [this blog](http://weblogs.asp.net/jgalloway/archive/2012/08/29/simplemembership-membership-providers-universal-providers-and-the-new-asp-net-4-5-web-forms-and-asp-net-mvc-4-templates.aspx) about new membership provider included in the mvc4 internet template I decided to replace my current custom nhibernate membership provider with the new one which support login using OAuth and OpenID. Also author in this above blog says that built in security was improved, so plenty of reasons for me.

As far as I'm understand I should implement ExtendedMembershipProvider in order to create my own nhibernate custom implementation with suppport for db other than mssql?

Any thoughts, links would be helpful.

Comment: Yes you need to inherit `ExtendedMembershipProvider` to create your own provider. This may help you [SimpleMemberhip Implementation](http://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/cbe82217ed89#src/WebMatrix.WebData/SimpleMembershipProvider.cs)

Comment: The above link is broken, this one works (for now): [SimpleMemberhip Implementation](http://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/c2ef1bfc4b8ea262883bc24affd1122f587f4305#src/WebMatrix.WebData/SimpleMembershipProvider.cs)

Answer (score 0):

this site [www.codehint.ru](http://www.codehint.ru) was implemented with realization ExtendedMembershipProvider and oAuth registration. And here is the russian article for replacing SimpleMembershipProvider with Custom provider inherited from ExtendedMembershipProvider [replacing SimpleMembership with custom ExtendedMembershipProvider](http://www.codehint.ru//articles/2013-04-16_extendedmembershipprovider_asp.net_mvc_4)